# How to add a photo to moderncv style banking

Tags: graphics, moderncv

I'm writing this post because I'm trying to let appear the photo on the `moderncv` using the `banking` style, but from default isn't possible.

So I would to know how to show the photo using the `banking` style and possibly putting the photo at the top of the first page above the name and title.

Comment: May I ask why you do not use style `classic` or `casual`? They both show the photo ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Simply because I love the banking format, whereas I don't like others:), but I need to add the photo:) thank you!!:)

Answer (score 15):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother
```

This checks whether you are using the `banking` style or not. If this is true, the photo is added at the top of the page, as you requested. If this is false, nothing changes, so you can use different styles even after have added this code to your document.

All you have to do is to use the command `\makecvtitle` as before. The photo is printed when you issue that command.

This is the result with the modified sample file `templates.tex` that accompanies the `moderncv` class after having set the style to `banking`:

> [image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PierGreenhearth Happy to help. Don't forget that you can accept an answer by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).

Answer (score 6):

You can check the file for the `casual` or `classic` variant of an `moderncv` cv, copy the banking style into a new style file in the same directory you have your cv, rename it for example to `moderncvstylemybanking.sty` (I added `my`) and copy the code from `cassual` into your local style `mybanking`.

So you will get with the new `moderncvstylemybanking.sty`

```
%% start of file `moderncvstylebanking.sty'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{moderncvstylemybanking}[2013/04/29 v1.5.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: banking]


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                required packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                overall style definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fonts
%\ifxetexorluatex
%  \setmainfont{Tex-Gyre Pagella}
%  \setsansfont{Tex-Gyre Pagella}
%  \setmathfont{Tex-Gyre Pagella}
%  \setmathfont[range=\mathit,\mathsfit]{Tex-Gyre Pagella Italic}
%  \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup,\mathbfsfup]{Tex-Gyre Pagella Bold}
%  \setmathfont[range=\mathbfit,\mathbfsfit]{Tex-Gyre Pagella Bold Italic}
%\else
  \IfFileExists{tgpagella.sty}%
    {%
      \RequirePackage{tgpagella}%
      \renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}}%
    {}
%\fi

% symbols
\moderncvicons{awesome}

% commands
\newcommand*{\maketitlesymbol}{%
    {~~~{\rmfamily\textbullet}~~~}}% the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
%   internal command to add an element to the footer
%   it collects the elements in a temporary box, and checks when to flush the box
\newsavebox{\maketitlebox}%
\newsavebox{\maketitletempbox}%
\newlength{\maketitlewidth}%
\newlength{\maketitleboxwidth}%


  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  %\newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  %\newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  %\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    %{\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%







\newif\if@firstmaketitleelement\@firstmaketitleelementtrue%
%   adds an element to the maketitle, separated by maketitlesymbol
%   usage: \addtomaketitle[maketitlesymbol]{element}
\newcommand*{\addtomaketitle}[2][\maketitlesymbol]{%
  \if@firstmaketitleelement%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#2}%
  \else%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}#1#2}\fi%
  \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
  \ifnum\maketitleboxwidth<\maketitlewidth%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{\usebox{\maketitletempbox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse%
  \else%
    \flushmaketitle{}\\%
    \savebox{\maketitlebox}{#2}%
    \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{#2}%
    \settowidth{\maketitleboxwidth}{\usebox{\maketitlebox}}%
    \@firstmaketitleelementfalse\fi}
%   internal command to flush the maketitle
\newcommand*{\flushmaketitle}{%
  \strut\usebox{\maketitlebox}%
  \savebox{\maketitlebox}{}%
  \savebox{\maketitletempbox}{}%
  \setlength{\maketitleboxwidth}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%

\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}

    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                resume style definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fonts
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\Huge\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\Huge\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\normalsize\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\upshape\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bfseries}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!85}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}

% lengths
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.3\textwidth}%
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}%
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}

% commands
\renewcommand*{\recomputecvlengths}{%
  \setlength{\quotewidth}{0.65\textwidth}%
  % main lenghts
  \setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth}%
  % listitem lengths
  \setlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\listitemsymbolwidth}%
  % doubleitem lengths
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \setlength{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}{0.5\doubleitemcolumnwidth}%
  % listdoubleitem lengths
  \setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}{\maincolumnwidth-\listitemsymbolwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\listitemsymbolwidth}%
  \setlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}{0.5\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}%
  % fancyhdr lengths
  \renewcommand{\headwidth}{\textwidth}%
  % regular lengths
  \setlength{\parskip}{0\p@}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \maketitle%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \strut\sectionstyle{#2}%
  {\color{color1}\hrule}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading}

\newcommand{\subsectionfill}{\xleaders\hbox to 0.35em{\scriptsize.}\hfill}% different subsectionfills will not be perfectly aligned, but remaining space at the end of the fill will be distributed evenly between leaders, so it will be barely visible
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \strut\subsectionstyle{#2}{\color{color1}{\subsectionfill}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{0.5ex}\@afterheading}

\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }{#3}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\hintstyle{#2}: #3\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#4}: }#5\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\cvlistitem}[2][.25em]{%
  \listitemsymbol\begin{minipage}[t]{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\cvlistdoubleitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{}{\listitemsymbol\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}%
    {}%
    {\listitemsymbol\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}}}}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newbox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}
\newlength{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}
\newlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}
\renewcommand*{\cvitemwithcomment}[4][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }#3}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}{\widthof{\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }#3\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedleft\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]%
  {%
    \bibliographyhead{\refname}%
%    \small%
    \begin{list}{\bibliographyitemlabel}%
      {%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth%
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
        \@openbib@code%
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty%
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
%        \sfcode`\.\@m%
%        \sfcode `\=1000\relax%
  }%
  {%
    \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \end{list}%
  }


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                letter style definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% commands
\renewcommand*{\recomputeletterlengths}{
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \setlength{\parskip}{6\p@}}

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender block
  \maketitle%
  \par%
   % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill % US style
%  \\[1em] % UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "April 6, 2006"; UK formal style: "05/04/2006"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}


\endinput
```

the result
[image]

Use this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{mybanking} % banking classic casual 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, 
% remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" 
% arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          % optional
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           % optional
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                             % optional
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}               % optional
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

I used `example-image-a`from package [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe). It must be installed but not loaded. A good package for making MWEs ...