# How to add photo in moderncv's banking style above the title

Tags: graphics, positioning, moderncv

I am using the site Overleaf in order to write my CV (`moderncv`'s `banking` style) and I would like to try to add a photo into it but I don't know how.

In the code says that the only thing I have to do is to uncomment this line:

```
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
```

Well I did that, also I uploaded my photo to Overleaf with title `picture.png` but nothing happens, my photo does not appear on CV. Here is proof:

[image]

Also please note that I would like to put my photo over my name not beside it, so I searched and [I found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131529/how-to-add-a-photo-to-moderncv-style-banking) that in order to happen that I should add these lines in my code:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother
```

Any ideas how to do that in Overleaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it the same way we did in your last question. Add this code before the line `\begin[document}`.

Please see this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\cfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}

\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother


% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}    

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data
\name{test}{test}
%\title{Biografik'o Shme'iwma}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{dress, city, postal}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{(+30) 325245345}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\email{test@gmail.com}                        
\social[linkedin]{gr.linkedin.com/in/test}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}

\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\homepagesymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\linkedinsocialsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

(I used a picture from pakage `mwe`that must be installed but not loaded)

Comment: oh man yes , i just pasted the lines at the beginning in wring place !!! thanks again you re awesome!!!